# What is Vector Graphics in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Can anyone explain to me about Vector Graphic in WPF.

I am trying to find out same using Google but did not get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: There is a section on Vector Graphics in the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Vector graphics are based on vectors (also called paths, or strokes)
>   which lead through locations called control points. Each of these
>   points has a definite position on the x and y axes of the work plan.
>   Each point, as well, is a variety of database, including the location
>   of the point in the work space and the direction of the vector (which
>   is what defines the direction of the track). Each track can be
>   assigned a color, a shape, a thickness and also a fill. This does not
>   affect the size of the files in a substantial way because all
>   information resides in the structure; it describes how to draw the
>   vector.

read more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics

> The difference between vector and raster graphics is that raster
>   graphics are composed of pixels, while vector graphics are composed of
>   paths. A raster graphic, such as a gif or jpeg, is an array of pixels
>   of various colors, which together form an image. A vector graphic,
>   such as an .eps file or Adobe Illustrator? file, is composed of paths,
>   or lines, that are either straight or curved. The data file for a
>   vector image contains the points where the paths start and end, how
>   much the paths curve, and the colors that either border or fill the
>   paths. Because vector graphics are not made of pixels, the images can
>   be scaled to be very large without losing quality. Raster graphics, on
>   the other hand, become "blocky," since each pixel increases in size as
>   the image is made larger. This is why logos and other designs are
>   typically created in vector format -- the quality will look the same
>   on a business card as it will on a billboard.

http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/vector_and_raster_graphics

Answer (score 5):

The short and sweet version is that vector graphics retain the same quality even when resized. This is because they are defined as functions (line goes from A to B, curve at this angle between these two points) rather than as an array of pixels.

WPF uses vector graphics for all controls and widgets, meaning they maintain their quality at any scale, and appear the same size of devices with different DPI screens.

WPF is tied closely to XAML, XAML is a markup language for describing vector graphics (amongst other things) For example a line might look like this:

```
<Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="25" X2="25" Y2="25" />
```

This will draw a line going from 0,25 to 25,25 - and it'll always be in that position regardless of screen size.

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit more about "line goes from A to B".In which format stores a A to B.

Comment: @NeerajDubey, I've added a small example for you.

Comment: To be more accurate, vector graphics are usually described using the SVG specification, which is XML-based. XAML is also XML-based, but it is specialized for different purposes. You can define .NET vector graphic objects in XAML, but you can't write SVG specification markup in a XAML file (or vice versa).